# Please help me make sense of the grammar of this line

Tags: grammaticality, literature

I am reading The Divine Comedy (Longfellow Translation), and ran into a sentence:

```
[Not very far as yet our way had gone
 This side the summit], when I saw a fire
 That overcame a hemisphere of darkness.
         (Inferno, Canto IV, lines 67-69)
```

The bracketed part - I suppose it means something like "we have not gone very far...", but I can't make out how it works in terms of grammar.  One would think there needs to be some kind of preposition between **the side** and **the summit**.  Then again, this is older writing and I am aware that older writing is different.

So how could I make sense of this line?

---

Not sure if it helps, but another translation (Cary) of the same lines goes as follows:

```
...We were not far
 On this side from the summit, when I kenn'd
 A flame, that o'er the darken'd hemisphere
 Prevailing shin'd.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Uh, it's poetic.  And ancient.

Comment: Longfellow's translation is intentionally Italianate, that is, meant to reflect something of the original language.  This essay is illuminating: ["How to Read Dante in the 21st Century"](https://theamericanscholar.org/how-to-read-dante-in-the-21st-century/#.XgE-AaaIbBJ).  The point being, much of Longfellow's translation is not written in grammatical, or typical English.

Comment: Yes, in standard Modern English -- and, I suspect, in standard 19th century English -- we would use a preposition or two in this clause. I'll explain this line of poetry to you if you explain this one to me: *’Twas brillig, and the slithy toves / Did gyre and gimble in the wabe: / All mimsy were the borogoves / And the mome raths outgrabe.*

Comment: @MikeGraham Not really a fair comparison, though. Those lines are from *Jabberwocky* by Lewis Carroll, which is an example of 'nonsense verse', 'humorous or whimsical verse that differs from other comic verse in its resistance to any rational or allegorical interpretation' [*(Britannica)*](https://www.britannica.com/art/nonsense-verse). Longfellow definitely didn't intend to turn (nor have others thought he turned)  *Inferno* into a species of non-allegorical whimsy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [*Ovid Unseens: Practice Passages for Latin Verse Translation and Comprehension*](https://books.google.com/books?id=33_jBAAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA20&dq=%22As%20common%20as%20omitted%20verbs%20are%20omitted%20prepositions.%20Poets%22&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q=%22As%20common%20as%20omitted%20verbs%20are%20omitted%20prepositions.%20Poets%22&f=false) we read that

> As common as omitted verbs are omitted prepositions. Poets frequently miss these little words out altogether and rely on the reader to understand them.

That's a comment about Latin poetry. But it is easy to imagine that some 19th century translators would use that device in their work.

**Discussion**

The [original text](https://web.archive.org/web/20201227221336/http://dantelab.dartmouth.edu/reader?reader%5Bcantica%5D=1&reader%5Bcanto%5D=4) is

> Non era lunga ancor la nostra via
> di qua dal sonno, quand' io vidi un foco
> ch'emisperio di tenebre vincia.

Google translate<sup>1</sup> renders it as

> Our way was not yet long
> this way from sleep, when I saw a fire
> that the hemisphere of darkness wins.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Well, not quite google translate on its own. In the original, I replaced the archaic word *emisperio* by its contemporary variant *emisfero* (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201227221618/https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/emispero/)). A better way to phrase that line is probably *that overcame a hemisphere of darkness,* like [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201227221733/https://dante.princeton.edu/cgi-bin/dante/campuscgi/mpb/GetCantoSection.pl?INP_POEM=Inf&INP_SECT=4&INP_START=61&INP_LEN=15&LANG=2).</sup>

[One commentary](https://web.archive.org/web/20201227221336/http://dantelab.dartmouth.edu/reader?reader%5Bcantica%5D=1&reader%5Bcanto%5D=4) says this about that line:

> The reading *sonno* (here 'sleep') has been much debated over the centuries. For a summarizing description of that debate see Mazzoni (“Saggio di un nuovo commento alla Divina Commedia: il Canto IV dell'Inferno,” Studi Danteschi 42 [1965]), pp. 119-20. Most modern editors accept *sonno*, and take the resulting expression to be a case of poetic compression: 'not far from sleep' = 'not far from the place where I had slept.'

So Longfellow has taken quite a bit of liberty with the translation of that line. He uses a similar construction in two other places:

> And the Guide said to me: “He wakes no more
> **This side the sound of the angelic trumpet;**
> (Canto 6)

and

> Down at the bottom were the sinners naked;
> **This side the middle came they facing us,**
> Beyond it, with us, but with greater steps;
> (Canto 18)

The omission of preposition is not unheard of in 19th century English poetry. [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=TiVHAQAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=%22The%20omission%20of%20prepositions%20other%20than%22&pg=PA215#v=onepage&q=%22The%20omission%20of%20prepositions%20other%20than%22&f=false) is a commentary on [Robert Browning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Browning) that makes a note of that.

Comment: Thank you! I knew that prepositions were sometimes omitted in languages where nouns were declined, but never imagined it happened in 19th century English.

Comment: @silmaril Well, in *poetic* 19th century English, in verse by (or translated by) possibly only a few poets.